# Why is my timer not working on Unity whenever I stop clicking?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on an Unity project and I need to count the time the user takes to make his next move.

Every object in the game moves by using the mouse and dragging it so whenever the user stops dragging the main object the timer should start and when the user drags the object again it should stop.

This is my script for the drag and the timer:

```
private float startPosX;
    private float startPosY;
    public bool isHeld;
    //private float distance = 10;
    private float stopTime;

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
        Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        Vector2 objectPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        transform.position = objectPos;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isHeld) {
        OnMouseDrag();
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        isHeld = false;
        Debug.Log(isHeld);
        stopTime += Time.deltaTime;
        string minutes = Mathf.Floor((stopTime % 3600) / 60).ToString("00");
        string seconds = (stopTime % 60).ToString("00");
        Debug.Log(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
}

private void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        isHeld = true;
        Debug.Log(isHeld);
    }
}
```

}

My onMouseDrag() is the actual function used to drag the object and on onMouseOver detects if the mouse is actually over the object.
The timer is given by deltaTime and then I use string minutes and seconds to display it in a nicer way and see if it is working correctly but it is not. I do not know why this is not working and I need some help because I am new to unity and coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things here that are causing you issues or are going to cause issues.

1. `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` returns `true` exactly once on the frame that the button release is detected in `Update()`. That being said, the code within `if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))` will only execute once on the frame that the mouse button is released. This is why you aren't seeing anything printed from `Debug.Log` or when you are, it's not correct.
2. Your usage of the modulo operator `%` is mathematically incorrect for the `minutes` portion of your code. `Mathf.Floor(stopTime / 60).ToString("00")` would get you minutes correctly.

I would suggest structuring it this way:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        isHeld = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isHeld = false;
        Debug.Log(isHeld);
        stopTime += Time.deltaTime;
        string minutes = Mathf.Floor(stopTime / 60).ToString("00");
        string seconds = (stopTime % 60).ToString("00");
        Debug.Log(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
}

private void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (isHeld) {
        Debug.Log(isHeld);
        OnMouseDrag();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this really helped me improve my code and solve my issue !

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read over the documentation for the `Input` class, in particular the `GetMouseButtonUp` function that you're checking:

> Returns true during the frame the user releases the given mouse
>   button.
>
> You need to call this function from the `Update` function, since the
>   state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user
>   has pressed the mouse button and released it again. button values are
>   `0` for left button, `1` for right button, `2` for the middle button.

You may have misunderstood what that function is doing.

This logs one message per click or release:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Debug.Log("once per click: mouse button clicked");
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        Debug.Log("once per click: mouse button released");
    }
}
```

This logs one message per frame:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        Debug.Log("once per frame: mouse button held");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("once per frame: mouse button NOT held");
    }
}
```

It just depends if you want something to happen once per click/release, or once per frame.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot !!